# Можно ли применить верстку к странице, сформированной сервлетом?

Tags: java, html, css, servlet

У меня есть сервлет, который формирует страницу с комобобоксом. Вопрос - могу ли я применить `CSS` к странице, сформированной этим сервлетом, и если да, то как?

```
    public class EditGenreServlet extends HttpServlet {

        public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            SocketConnection.output.println("load_genres");
            String sourceString = SocketConnection.input.readLine();
            HashMap<String, String> genres = Parser.getNamedObjectMap(SourceString);
            out.println("<html><body>");
            out.println("<select>");
            for (String string : genres.values()) {
                out.println("<option>" + string + "</option>");
            }
            out.println("</select>");
            out.println("</body></html>");
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно. Нужно просто распечатать нужный вам HTML с помощью вызовов out.println

Например,

```
out.println("<html><body>");
out.println("<style>");
out.println(".invisible {display:none;}");
out.println("</style>");
out.println("<select class=\"invisible\">");
```

Важно, что для серьезных приложени распечатка текста HTML вручную не является желательной, нужно использовать средства типа [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org)

Если же под "применить CSS" вы подразумевали применение какого-то готового CSS-файла, то подключить его можно аналогично

```
out.println("<html>
out.println("<head>");
out.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"styles.css\"">
out.println("</head>");
out.println("<body>");
out.println("<select class=\"invisible\">");
```

Этот готовый CSS-файл, конечно, еще нужно каким-то образом отдать. Можно отдать его прямо из java с помощью сервлета по другому урлу, но самый частый способ - это раздача статических файлов с серверов, специально предназначенных для раздачи статики, например, [Энджайниксом](http://nginx.org/).

Если раздать с помощью внешних систем никак не получается - можно вычитать нужный CSS из файла на жестком диске, и потом распечатать его в том же самом сервлете. У разных фреймворков свои способы читать файлы, поэтому привожу вариант просто на чистой джаве (пример дан для Java 8):

```
String cssContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("styles.css")));

out.println("<html><body>");
out.println("<style>");
out.println(cssContent);
out.println("</style>");
out.println("<select class=\"invisible\">");
```

Comment: А можно отдельно подключить css-файл?

Comment: Обновил ответ двумя новыми способами